# How can I pass a string variable from a groovy class file to the controller?

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I am building a Grails application where I have pulled out username from the MySQL database in side the `src/groovy/UserDetail.groovy` class. I have stored it inside def user. How can I pass this to my controller to display it in my view?

Comment: Are you using Spring Security?

Comment: Yes i am using spring security (CAS)

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the current user within your controller you can use the springSecurityService. The [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html#6.2%20SpringSecurityService) includes an example of doing this. From there you can access any property of the UserDetail.

Answer (score 0):

to display it in your view let say

```
def list ()
{
def user = springSecurityService.currentUser(); // or below

def user = UserDetail.findByUser(springSecurityService.currentUser().id)

[userDetail:user]  //pass it to list view

}
```

if not it is bit unclear question to what you want ?